# Is possible to make a site multilanguage in TYPO3 when your menu is static?

Tags: typo3, menuitem

I want to include a nav-item in my static menu from where i can change the site language.

Comment: What is _static menu_ in your case? why don't you use `HMENU` cObject?

Comment: With static menu i mean i have hard coded it in (Main.html file), used bootstrap. I have not used the HMENU. And i wonder if it is possible to make the site multilanguage. Is there any any way. Or i have to use only the HMENU?

Comment: No, It's not possible, static code will be static, nevermind if it's TYPO3, WordPress, Drupal, Symfony or even pure PHP. You can try to modify it with JavaScript, but it does not make sense. Instead, you should build your menu with `HMENU` in TypoScript. It should be quite easy, especially when you have working HTML with CSS and JS (maybe). You just need to recreate it with TypoScript.

Comment: Ok thank you biesior for your answer

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use? In version 8 and newer you can use a DataProcessor in TypoScript (which is obviously easier to integrate than the classic HMENU).

Comment: I am using version 10.4.5. I am new to typo and the menu part to me is vague.Thank you Thomas i will see how DataProcessor works

Comment: @ThomasLöffler can i use DataProcessor also for the footer?

Comment: You can use DataProcessor whereever you want in your template, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to create DataProcessor and how to handle it in Fluid templates.

TypoScript:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  layoutRootPath = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
  partialRootPath = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
  file = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html

  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    10 {
      entryLevel = 0
      levels = 2
      expandAll = 1
      as = mainNav
    }
    20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    20 {
      special = directory
      # This number is the sysfolder holding the header navigation pages
      special.value = 11
      as = headerNav
    }
    30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\LanguageMenuProcessor
    30 {
      languages = auto
      as = languageNav
    }
    40 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    40 {
      special = directory
      # This number is the sysfolder holding the footer navigation pages
      special.value = 13
      as = footerNav
    }
  }
}
```

In Fluid you get an array with all pages fetched by the different DataProcessors:

```html
<f:if condition="{mainNav}">
    <ul class="nav-main">
        <f:for each="{mainNav}" as="item">
            <li class="nav-main__item{f:if(condition: '{item.active}', then: ' nav-main__item-active')}">
                <a href="{item.link}">
                    {item.title}
                </a>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:if>
```

Or the language menu:

```html
<f:for each="{languageNav}" as="item">
    <li class="language__item">
        <f:if condition="{item.active}">
            <f:then>
                <span>{item.navigationTitle}</span>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                <a href="{item.link}">{item.navigationTitle}</a>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </li>
</f:for>
```

Of course you can choose your own classes and structure, but this possibility gives you a much easier integration.

Hope, it helps